Hide the Elementor Pro Popup by detecting session data
we created a WordPress website using Elementor Pro and by using theme builder
we created a Popup which will be show On Page Load within (sec) 6.
if the user submit the form we captured the data and save the formSubmitted session true
for 15 minutes in session Storage so for next 15 minutes we will not show the Popup.
But we can't able to catch that Popup because it's dynamically loading.
i tried two codes from elementor website
elementor/popup/show – when a Popup is opened/shown
elementor/popup/hide – when a Popup is closed/hidden

but these are not relevant to me because i want to stop that popup
to trigger if session id is there.
